Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval'

I need help from community, when i run project nextjs sxa sitecore with jss start:connected in http://localhost:3000 then issue in image raise in console log of chrome.
I investigate to check issue and fix using solution in stackover and other sites but that seem still not work. One of these solution is change Content-Security-Policy in next.config.js still not work.
When run local in firefox then message be like:

